# How to get time in hours,minutes,seconds from this format 0:02:54.000000 in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have genrated time in this format 0:02:54.000000

Now I want to display that time in hours = 0, Minutes = 02, Seconds = 54 from above time. How do I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String input = '0:02:54.000000';
final split = input.split(RegExp('[:.]'));
String hours = split[0];
String minutes = split[1];
String seconds = split[2];
```

Comment: Why did you used `RegExp`? It works with `input.split(':');`

Comment: @Warjeh i'm also splitting the dot

Comment: Ah. I didn't see that. Sorry.